# asp.net inline override

Tags: asp.net, overriding, inline-code

If I'm writing in-line code on a .aspx page is it possible to override the onLoad of the class that the .aspx is directly inheriting from?

Right now if I do the override the base.onLoad inline on the .aspx page it is overriding the "Page" object's onLoad event not the class the .aspx is inheriting from.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try creating a class inline in your aspx page?

```
<script runat="server">
    public class MyPage : MyBaseClass
    {
        protected override OnLoad....
    }
</script>
```

and then have your aspx header inherit from MyPage

Comment: consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612420/calling-the-original-page-load-fuction-from-inline-code#) answer for better understanding.